# Rank one decomposition of a positive semi-definite matrix with inequality trace constraints

Tags: matrix-decomposition, svd

Suppose there is a square matrix $A$ and a positive semi-definite matrix $X\in\Re^n$, such that
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{trace}(AX)\leq0
\end{equation}
Is there any ways I could do the rank one decomposition of matrix $X$, such that for $r\leq n$,
\begin{equation}
X=\sum_{k=1}^{r} x_kx_k^\top 
\end{equation}
and keep the inquality constraints
\begin{equation}
x_k^\top A x_k = \mathrm{trace}(A(x_kx_k^\top))\leq0 \qquad \forall k
\end{equation}
Or at least hold for one $x_{k}$?

Many thanks!